# How to limit the background colour I put on text

Tags: html, css, colors, background

How can I limit the length of the background colour I place on text?

I'm messing around with a pretty basic site just to re-jog my memory of HTML and all the different elements, I'm using an external stylesheet and I have used this code:

```css
li:nth-child(4) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

and the line that this is affecting is:

```
<li>And this will have a yellow background!</li>
```

Now, the colour does show up only it highlights the text and the rest of the webpage line that the text is sat on, how do I set it so that the text and nothing else has a background? Is there a simple css solution or will I have to resort to placing it within a div tag?

Answer (score 4):

Because the LI will automatically stretch to the rest of the page. Just add the following to your LI style:

```
display:inline-block;
```

And that should hopefully solve the problem.

That will display the LI's in a horizontal line however. An alternative would be to add another element within the LI e.g. a `<span>`

So:

```
<li>And this will have a yellow background!</li>
```

Becomes:

```
<li><span>And this will have a yellow background!</span></li>
```

And then just do something like this in your CSS:

```
li:nth-child(4)>span { background:yellow; }
```

See [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/W5KC5/1/)

Comment: add a fiddle...and you have nailed the answer!! :)